# ¿Cómo convertir datos leídos en Java de Excel a XML?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Me gustaría saber como puedo convertir datos leídos por una clase Java que me permite leer documentos en Excel `.xls` , `.xlsx` y `.xlsm` mediante la librería `POI` a una estructura `XML`, cabe mencionar que la clase lee los archivos y me muestra los resultados en consola.

Ahora, ¿cómo podría generar una estructura XML a partir de esos datos?, ¿necesito alguna librería en específico o qué puedo hacer?

Adjunto el código que lee los datos de Excel:

```
public class ExcelReader{


public void displayFromExcel() throws  FileNotFoundException, IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException
{


File archivoExcel = new File("C:\\Users\\1\\Desktop\\archivo.xlsx"); //ruta del archivo xls o xlsx
Workbook libroExcel = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivoExcel)); //crear un libro excel
Sheet hojaActual = libroExcel.getSheetAt(0); //acceder a la primera hoja

Row filaActual = hojaActual.getRow(0); //acceder a la primera fila en la hoja
Cell celdaActual = filaActual.getCell(0); //acceder a la primera celda en la fila

Iterator<Row> rows = hojaActual.rowIterator();

while (rows.hasNext())
{

    Row row = (Row) rows.next(); 
    int rowNumber = row.getRowNum();
    // muestra el número de fila
    System.out.println ("No. Fila: " + rowNumber);

    filaActual= rows.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cells = filaActual.cellIterator();
    while (cells.hasNext())
    {
        celdaActual= cells.next();

         cells.remove();

        if (celdaActual.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
        {
            System.out.println("String: "+celdaActual.getStringCellValue()+" ");
        }
        else if(celdaActual.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
        {
            System.out.println("Int: "+celdaActual.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
        }
        else
        {
            //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, FileNotFoundException, InvalidFormatException, IOException
{
    MyExp exp = new MyExp();
    exp.displayFromExcel();
}
```

}

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando recomendaciones acerca de libros, herramientas, librerías de software, tutoriales o recursos externos al site son off-topic, ya que las mismas generan respustas basadas en opiniones o gustos particulares así como spam.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el formato del XML que quieres generar?

Comment: Si entiendes algo de inglés puedes ir dándole un vistazo a esto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357610/parse-excel-data-to-xml-using-java , igual debe haber varias maneras de realizar lo que deseas.

Comment: gracias de echo hace un tiempo me base en esta pregunta para poder hacer la conversión a XML el detalle es que sólo funciona para archivos .xls  y yo lo necesito para archivos .xls, .xlsx y.xlsm he probado usar una variación de mi código con este pero siempre tengo el siguiente error al hacer el parsing a XML:    `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre recuerda que en programación (y en el mundo del software en general) los problemas se pueden simplificar utilizando [divide y vencerás](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_et_impera). Entonces, tu problema puede ser dividido en las siguientes partes (cada una más sencilla si se ve como problema puntual):

1. Leer el contenido de un archivo Excel. (hecho)
2. Almacenar datos en una clase Java desde un archivo Excel. (por hacer)
3. Convertir los datos de un objeto Java a XML. (por hacer)

Al parecer, solo debes continuar con las partes 2 y 3. Dado que no conocemos cómo lucen los datos de tu archivo Excel o cómo quieres que estén estructurados, la parte 2 dependerá de tus necesidades. Para la parte 3, puedes utilizar JAXB que es nativo de Java o alguna librería externa. Personalmente, yo recomiendo el uso de [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) con `StaxDriver` (Aviso Legal<sup>1</sup>: No estoy asociado de ninguna manera al proyecto XStream ni al equipo de desarrollo, solo soy un usuario contento con el producto y sus resultados).

---

<sup>1</sup> [Aviso Legal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviso_legal) parece ser una buena traducción al español de Disclaimer

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, con el código que proporcioné tengo una salida en consola como esta:   Int: 6.91902030165E12 
String: ADVENTURE WHEELS 
String: FOB- Free On Board 
Int: 11.0 
String: CHINA 
String: Shantou 
Int: 6.0 
Int: 1000.0 
String: FCL 
String: 40RF 
String: GS 
String: WGS SHANGHAI 
Int: 1.442773 
String: DIA DEL NINO 
Int: 1000.0 
Int: 228.19995000000003 
String: LC- At Sight 
Int: 16.5 
Int: 499.0 
String: New     , cómo me recomendarías hacer el paso 2 para poder continuar con el paso 3, de antemano muchas gracias de nuevo, saludos!

Comment: @Ivan te recomiendo crear una clase de transferencia (conocido como DTO o Data Transfer Object) en base a esos datos. Por ejemplo, la clase se puede llamar `Producto` o algo asociado al concepto que posee esa información. Luego, crear un campo por cada celda de información en la fila de tu archivo Excel. Por ejemplo, ADVENTURE WHEELS parece ser el `nombre` del `Producto`, CHINA parece ser el `pais` del `Producto`, y asi. Si hay otra persona con la que puedas consultar al respecto, pues hazle las preguntas respectivas sobre ello, o define esto tú mismo.

Comment: me ha servido mucho tu ayuda, acabo de modificar mi código que posteo aquí por el final que me permite leer cualquier extensión de excel, y estuve dándole una buena revisada a la Xstream y ya agregué los .jar a mi classpath, me podrías ayudar a decirme como puedo implementarla usando el código que tengo para hacer el parsing a XML? de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: @Ivan si vas a usar XStream te recomiendo que empieces revisando la página en el vínculo indicado en la pregunta (los vínculos no están para que la pregunta se vea más bonita), específicamente [esta parte](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html) donde te muestra un tutorial directo de cómo usar XStream para serializar objetos Java a XML.

Comment: si de echo ya los revisé e intenté hacer la serialización a XML siguiendo los tutoriales y no tengo ningún problema el detalle es que no veo donde se guarda el archivo XML o no se si de verdad se esta serializando mi información

Comment: @Ivan según el vínculo del tutorial, esta es la línea más importante: `String xml = xstream.toXML(...);`. El XML se almacena en ese String, y ya te corresponde manejar ese String a como gustes, sea mostrarlo en un log o crear un archivo u otro uso.