# ¿Cómo exportar los datos de un XML a excel usando java?

Tags: java

Buenas tardes,

estoy tratando de extraer el contenido de un XML para escribirlo en un excel, tendrán alguna referencia para realizarlo.

Comment: Buenas @Raymundo ! Podrías incluir el código con el que intentas extraer el contenido del XML en la pregunta? Así nos ayudas a ayudarte! De paso te invito a que te pases por [el tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/Tour) para que aprendas un poco sobre como funciona la comunidad, saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Raymundo. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asimismo, te recomiendo que revises [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Adicional, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de una pregunta similar para que sepas cómo construir tu pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1948/227

Comment: Es la primera vez que voy a interactuar con XML, por eso pregunte por una referencia, algo que me ayude a empezar con esto.

Answer (score 2):

Un ejemplo simple de como leer un XML, navegar por sus nodos y leer sus datos (ejemplo simplificado de http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm):

Contenido de alumnos.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<clase>
   <alumno num="11">
      <nombre>Luis</nombre>
      <calificacion>85</calificacion>
   </alumno>
   <alumno num="15">
      <nombre>Jaime</nombre>
      <calificacion>70</calificacion>
   </alumno>
   <alumno num="17">
      <nombre>Pedro</nombre>
      <calificacion>90</calificacion>
   </alumno>
</clase>
```

Código:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;

....    

File inputFile = new File("alumnos.xml"); //Ruta al archivo XML

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

//Ejemplo de obtener el nombre de una etiqueta
System.out.println("Elemento raiz :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
//Se buscan todos los nodos con la etiqueta "alumno"
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("alumno");

//Se itera por cada nodo para extraer los datos
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    Node nNode = nList.item(i);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        //Obtener el valor de un atributo:
        System.out.println("Estudiante número:"
                + eElement.getAttribute("num"));
        //Obtener el contenido de una etiqueta
        System.out.println("Nombre : "
                + eElement
                .getElementsByTagName("nombre")
                .item(0)
                .getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Calificacion : "
                + eElement
                .getElementsByTagName("calificacion")
                .item(0)
                .getTextContent());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Elemento raiz :clase
----------------------------
Estudiante número:11
Nombre : Luis
Calificacion : 85
----------------------------
Estudiante número:15
Nombre : Jaime
Calificacion : 70
----------------------------
Estudiante número:17
Nombre : Pedro
Calificacion : 90
```

Este ejemplo lo puedes probar sin necesidad de librerías externas, pero tiene rendimiento bajo, si necesitas un mejor rendimiento hay otras librerias que puedes [usar](http://mvnrepository.com/open-source/xml-processing).

Ya que tengas los datos para armar el Excel te recomiendo Apache POI, para esto necesitas conseguir la libreria. Si tienes Maven o un administrador de dependencia lo puedes agregar a tu pom.xml:

```
<!--
  (Te puedes meter a esta liga para descargarlo manualmente) 
  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi 
 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

de lo contrario lo puedes descargar de la pagina oficial: https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Para crear un archivo:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

// Crear renglon y ponerle celdas.
Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
// Crear celda y ponerle un valor
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(1);

// Tambien se pueden crear en una sola linea
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString("Esto es un String"));

// Escribir el archivo
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

En la parte de "Escribir el archivo" lo va a escribir directo a la carpeta donde esta corriendo el programa, no nos has dicho si tu archivo lo quieres servir asi o si necesitas mandarlo a un navegador. Si tienes dudas especificas puedes volver a preguntar.
Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @JuanAlgaba. Las respuestas deben ser auto contenidas, es decir que su contenido debe tener todo lo necesario para responder la pregunta, los enlaces deben ser información adicional y de apoyo para la pregunta como para profundizar más. Tu respuesta es buena, sería genial si pudieses agregarle la lectura del XML.

Comment: Como desarrollador Java, te comento que Java provee métodos para lectura de XML, pero está comprobado que tienen muy bajo rendimiento, por ello es mejor acudir a librerías externas como XStream que lo trabajan más rápido.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hecho.